# Ajuda em 2 questões de Arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Tem essa função para descobrir em quantos meses o saldo de uma pessoa foi positivo:

```
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo){

let quantidade = 0;

for(let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++){
    if(umPeriodo[mes] > 0)
        quantidade += 1;
}

return quantidade;
}
```

Agora precisava escrever um código (na mesma estrutura que este acima) para saber em quantos meses de um período houve perda (quando o saldo é menor que zero).

Aí essa seria a **primeira questão**, para escrever a função **quantidadeDeMesesComPerda**.

A **segunda questão** seria essa:

> Saber o saldo dos meses com lucro

Complete a função saldoDeMesesComLucro. Novamente tem uma estrutura similar com os problemas anteriores, porém não tão rápido! Esta função precisa retornar um array.

saldosDeMesesComLucro([100, 20, 0, -10, 10])
[100, 20, 10]

Alguém me ajuda por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thiago,

No primeiro problema, está bem simples, como a função deve ter a mesma estrutura da função `quantidadeDeMesesComLucro`, basta criar a função `quantidadeDeMesesComPerda`, mas com a comparação de valores invertida.

Na função quantidadeDeMesesComLucro, a comparação de valores utiliza o maior `>`:

```
if(umPeriodo[mes] > 0)
```

Essa condição na função `quantidadeDeMesesComPerda` terá a comparação contrária, utilizando o menor `<`, logo a função ficará da seguinte forma:

```js
const meses = [100, 20, 0, -10, 10];

function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo){
  let quantidade = 0;

  for(let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++){
    if(umPeriodo[mes] < 0)
      quantidade += 1;
  }

  return quantidade;
}

console.log(quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(meses));
```

---

Agora, alterando a função `quantidadeDeMesesComLucro` para retornar um array, podemos facilmente alterar a variável que é um contador na função (`quantidade`) e utilizarmos um array no lugar da mesma, sendo que no trecho `quantidade += 1;`, iremos utilizar o método push do array:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(umPeriodo){
  let periodos = [];

  for(let mes = 0; mes < umPeriodo.length; mes++){
    if(umPeriodo[mes] > 0)
      periodos.push(umPeriodo[mes]);
  }

  return periodos;
}

const meses = [100, 20, 0, -10, 10];

console.log(quantidadeDeMesesComLucro(meses));
```

Veja que inicializei o array com um valor vazio `[]`, isso é importante, caso contrário será gerada uma exceção ao tentar utilizar o método push.

> Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Ah entendi! No caso o raciocínio da função quantidadeDeMesesComPerda é pra retornar um número, por isso se usa o contador. E no raciocínio da segunda função, eu estou retornando um valor dentro do array né, por isso o método push. Seria mais ou menos isso?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo.